# Условие If в Android

Tags: javascript

Всё проще простого. Есть строка с полученными данными, её нужно проверить, если в ней есть знак +, то одно действие, если другое, то другое. Что-то типа того

```
if (string4 содержит +)
{действия}
else
 {действия2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((string4.indexOf('+') != -1)
{действия}
else
{действия2}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но на string4 пишет ошибку
    The method indexOf(int) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)

Comment: поправил скобки.